# Create bitmap from byte[]

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am doing an Android application that depends on camera. 
I have the function `public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)`where arrives frames when are ready. Now I need convert this `byte[] data` to `Bitmap`. I've read a lot of solutions and I found one that runs OK but it's so slow, about 250 ms in a LG Optimus G:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

int width = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
int height = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
ByteArrayOutputStream outstr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, width,
        height, null);
yuvimage.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, outstr);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outstr.toByteArray(),
        0,
outstr.size());
```

Is there other way to do this? Becasuse this way is not optimal if I want process with high frame rate.

Comment: Do not use YuvImage as intermediate. Use `data` parameter directly in decodeByteArray().

Comment: can you give me any example? thanks

Comment: Why do you ask? You should realise that @Ircover exactly showed you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

2 things that could help speed things up:

#1 instead of the hard-coded ImageFormat.NV21 use the format from parameters.getPreviewFormat()

#2 go down with the quality

Comment: yeah, go down quality is an option but i prefer found other solutions that not affect it

Comment: try how far you get with #1 - I have no more ideas than those 2 things at the moment. You could also try PNG - sure it is wrong for pics usually - but in this case it could be an option as you do not really want the reduced size of the jpeg - you just want some metadata around your image-data

Answer (score 0):

Just call [decodeByteArray(byte[] data, int offset, int length)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html). That should be faster.

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

Comment: By the way, `decodeByteArray` returns null if it could not get image from your `byte[]`.

Comment: @Ircover it also returns null for uncompressed raw-data

Comment: Where do you have uncompressed raw-data? I dont understand your remark at all. Example?

Comment: I think that your solutions runs ok when byte[] is obtain by read file or something like that, but camera gives, as says @ligi, raw data

Comment: No. Normally not. What did you do with that camera? Please explain. Normally data[] contains the bytes of a jpg image.

Comment: @greenapps afaik this is only possible with API level 21: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#JPEG

Comment: Sorry. I apoligise. Seems that it does not contain a jpg. Ok looks like raw data indeed. (Saved it to file but no app can display it. You know an app who can?). Sorry for the confusion.